# How to set and record alerts for Jenkin server down and up

Tags: linux, ksh, jenkins

I have Jenkins pipeline job which goes thought all our Jenkins servers and check the connectivity (runs every few minutes).

ksh file:

```
#!/bin/ksh
JENKINS_URL=$1

    curl  --connect-timeout 10 "$JENKINS_URL" >/dev/null
    status=`echo $?`
     if [ "$status" == "7" ]; then
        export SUBJECT="Connection refused or can not connect to URL $JENKINS_URL"
        echo "$SUBJECT"|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t XXXX@gmail.com

    else
        echo "successfully connected $JENKINS_URL"
     fi

    exit 0
```

I would like to add another piece of code, which record all the times that server was down (it should include the name of the server and timestamp) into a file, and in case the server is up again, send an email which will notify about it, and it will be also recorded in the file. I don't want to get extra alerts, only one alert (to file and mail) when it's down, and one when it's up again. any idea how to implement it?

Comment: You need to store the state of the servers. Perhaps the simplest way would be to create a directory "down" . When you get your status 7 then see if down/$server exists. If it doesn't then send mail and touch the file. If the status is not 7 then see if down/$server exists. If it does exist then send mail saying the server is up and remove the down/$server file. BTW, you can say `status=$?` rather than `status=\`echo $?\``, and you don't need to export the SUBJECT variable.

Comment: Good idea. In addition I can create one more file, which won't be removed, and will keep the times on when it was up and down.  Can you suggest your way for coding your suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/ksh
JENKINS_URL=$1
# extract just the host and potental port number from the url
HOSTP=${JENKINS_URL#*:} ; HOSTP=${HOSTP%%/*}

# Create down directory if it doesn't exist
[ -d down ] || mkdir -p down

curl  --connect-timeout 10 "$JENKINS_URL" >/dev/null
status=$?
if [ "$status" == "7" ]; then
    [ -e "down/$HOSTP" ] && exit 0
    { echo -n "$HOSTP   down    " ; date } >> times
    touch "down/$HOSTP"
    SUBJECT="Connection refused or can not connect to URL $JENKINS_URL"
    echo "$SUBJECT"|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t XXXX@gmail.com
else
    echo "successfully connected $JENKINS_URL"
    [ -e "down/$HOSTP" ] || exit 0
    rm "down/$HOSTP"
    { echo -n "$HOSTP    up     " ; date } >> times
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: Tnx, I didn't use the exact code but took the general idea

Comment: @arielma That is entirely right and proper. You know what your requirements are better than a random stranger on the internet.